# How do you calculate the heat of a reaction given a table of heat of formation values?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, ions, concentration

[image: USNCO 2016 Local #20]

So I've been trying to answer this question, and as far as I've learned it's $\Delta H^0_{\mathrm f}$(products)-$\Delta H^0_{\mathrm f}$(reactants), multiplying each by number of moles and such.

Trying to use that on this problem I came up with $\ce{0.008 OH- + 0.008 HCO3- -> 0.008 H2O + 0.008 CO3^2-}$ after (possibly incorrectly) noting that $\ce{HCO3}$ was in excess. However, this does not yield anywhere near the correct answer of C. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can obtain the correct answer using your values. Maybe double check for mistakes and typos?

Here are my quick calculations:
The overall reaction is:

$\ce{NaHCO3 + NaOH -> Na2CO3 + H2O}$

The equation used is:
\begin{equation}
\Delta H_\text{reaction}^\circ = \sum {\Delta H_{f}^\circ(\text{Products})} - \sum {\Delta H_{f}^\circ(\text{Reactants})}
\end{equation}

$\Delta H_\text{products}^\circ= (\pu{0.008 mol}\times\pu{-286 kJ/mol} +\pu{0.008 mol}\times\pu{-677 kJ/mol}) = \pu{-7.704 kJ}$

$\Delta H_\text{reactants}^\circ= (\pu{0.008 mol}\times\pu{-692 kJ/mol} +\pu{0.008 mol}\times\pu{-230 kJ/mol}) = \pu{-7.376 kJ}$

$\Delta H_\text{reaction}^\circ = (-7.074 - (-7.376))~\pu{kJ/mol} = \pu{-0.328 kJ} = \pu{-328 J}$

Comment: Thank you! You helped me realize that I'm a buffoon and that the table is in kJ whereas the answers are in J. :P

Comment: No problem. Could you mark the question as answered?

Comment: Interesting that the significant figures in the book answer seem to be wrong. I'd agree that the answer should be -328 not -330.